# Re-applying for a UK visa after getting a refusal due to discrepancy between my stated monthly expenditure and the monthly debits in my bank statement

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image]

I recently had my standard visa application refused due to a discrepancy between my stated monthly expenditure and the monthly debits reflected in my bank statement. In my application, I listed my average monthly expenses as £150, while my bank statement showed £650 in debits. I only submitted one month's bank statement, which coincidentally included a payment towards my university fee that month. The £150 I stated in my application solely encompasses my living expenses, excluding the university fee.

Furthermore, on reviewing my subsequent two months' bank statements, I found that they also reflect similar debit amounts of around £600. These are largely due to unexpected transactions such as paying for friends or instances where gas stations verify my card balance by debiting £30 and then crediting it back to my account.

Given this situation, I have a few queries regarding my next steps:

1. In my second application, should I revise my monthly expenditure to match the bank statement, or maintain the same amount and explain the additional transactions?
2. Would it be advisable to include an explanation for the discrepancy leading to my current visa refusal in a cover letter accompanying my new application?
3. I would greatly appreciate any further tips or suggestions for improving my next application.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: See the main answer to the linked question, which should tell you everything you wanted to know about submitting bank statements correctly. In short, submitting just one monthly statement is a terrible idea and it was probably guaranteed to sink your application.

Comment: *…instances where gas stations verify my card balance by debiting £30 and then crediting it back to my account* - pre-authorisations normally only result in *one* charge on your statement: the actual amount of fuel purchased. Authorisation holds don’t typically show up at all. If reapplying rapidly after a very recent refusal, you need your financials to be transparent with no complicated explanations. If I were you, I’d stop ‘paying for friends’ and wait a while until you have enough ‘clean’ statements to convince an ECO. How is travel to UK for business consistent with university studies?

Comment: Thank you. @Traveller I have checked my bank statement and the pre-authorisations does affect the final debit amount. I work remotely with a company who wishes me to be there for two weeks for some on site work.

Comment: @TooTea Thank you that's really helpful!

Comment: "company who wishes me to be there for two weeks for some on site work" note that this requires work authorisation (or lying on the application, if you request a tourist visa).